# W3C can't check live site: error "403 ok"

Tags: html, w3c-validation

I was asked by my supervisor to create a website for our [small] company, but while attempting to validate the live site, it tells me that it can't check the document: "I got the following unexpected response when trying to retrieve http://www.barroncountyhousingauthority.com/:
403 OK"

I've researched the "403 ok" error and looked at my source code, but so far no dice. What would be causing this to happen?

Answer (score 0):

Most modern browsers will handle malformed html very well. And as a result pages load without you seeing the problem.

The issue with your site is that it is missing the opening `<html>` tag which is causing all of these issues. The `doctype` is used to define the standards expected in the page, and while it does state `html` as the value, that is just a reference to the new *HTML 5* version.

[image]

This should look like this instead

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="generator" content="HTML Tidy for Linux (vers 25 March 2009), see www.w3.org">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

Comment: Thanks, Travis J, I can't believe I missed something that ridiculously simple!
Unfortunately, applying the <html> tag didn't work; I'm still getting the same error message (for reasons that are beyond me, validating via file upload or direct input works just fine).
I'm wondering if there's a chance that it could be something to do with servers (or something similar) on my host's side.